# Sitecore 9.1 installation error : "Notfound issue solr creating core "

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

I am installing `Sitecore 9.1 with SIF` and I am using `Solr 7.2.1` version.

installation fails due to the below error.

**Below my error in Powershell:**

> [--------------------------------------------------
>   XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------] [XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting]
>   https://localhost:8984/solr/ [XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[SolrCore]
>   Performing Create on https://localhost:8984/solr/
>
> [ERROR] Install-SitecoreConfiguration : NotFound -
>   https://localhost:8984/solr//admin/cores?action=Create&name=sc910_xdb&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json
>   [ERROR] At C:\resourcefiles\new resource
>   files\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:93 char:1 [ERROR] +
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec
>   ... [ERROR] +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException [ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
> [ERROR]   [TIME] 00:00:35
> ```

How to proceed from here?

**Below Solr logs: [but no clue]**

> 2019-01-31 14:26:57.135 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server
>   jetty-9.3.20.v20170531 2019-01-31 14:26:57.923 INFO  (main) [   ]
>   o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  **_      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™
>   version 7.2.1 2019-01-31 14:26:57.924 INFO  (main) [   ]
>   o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / __|** | | _   Starting in standalone
>   mode on port 8984 2019-01-31 14:26:57.924 INFO  (main) [   ]
>   o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter __ / _ \ | '*|  Install dir:
>   C:\solr-7.2.1\solr-7.2.1 2019-01-31 14:26:57.937 INFO  (main) [   ]
>   o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter |*/_/*|*|    Start time:
>   2019-01-31T14:26:57.925Z 2019-01-31 14:26:57.955 INFO  (main) [   ]
>   o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Using system property solr.solr.home:
>   C:\solr-7.2.1\solr-7.2.1\server\solr 2019-01-31 14:26:57.962 INFO 
>   (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading container configuration
>   from C:\solr-7.2.1\solr-7.2.1\server\solr\solr.xml 2019-01-31
>   14:26:58.558 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Found 0
>   core definitions underneath C:\solr-7.2.1\solr-7.2.1\server\solr
>   2019-01-31 14:26:59.184 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started
>   @2696ms 2019-01-31 14:42:02.883 INFO  (Thread-0) [   ]
>   o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Shutting down CoreContainer instance=2036127838
>   2019-01-31 14:42:02.883 INFO  (Thread-0) [   ]
>   o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for
>   registry=solr.node, tag=null 2019-01-31 14:42:02.883 INFO  (Thread-0)
>   [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for
>   registry=solr.jvm, tag=null 2019-01-31 14:42:02.883 INFO  (Thread-0) [
>   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for
>   registry=solr.jetty, tag=null 2019-01-31 14:42:02.884 INFO  (Thread-0)
>   [   ] o.a.s.c.TransientSolrCoreCacheDefault Allocating transient cache
>   for 2147483647 transient cores

Comment: Couple things to check/try.1.) Errors you get when you go to https://localhost:8984/solr/. 2.)  Check for any process listening on port 443 using the following command. netstat -aon | find /i ":443". You will need to temporarily stop the process. 3.) Try a different port.

Comment: The other thing I would check is to make sure that the SolrRoot parameter is correct.  The default is C:\solr-7.2.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looking at the url for the solr in the error description it seem like there is a "/ " to much 
- https://localhost:8984/solr//admin

ensure your parameter in the powershell doesn’t contain a traling '/'

should be something like
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8984/solr"

Comment: This worked. You should remove trailing '/'

Comment: It worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue few days ago and it was only the Solr server URL.

> https://localhost:8984

Make sure it is really localhost (that was my error, my script was creating the server at https://solr:xxxx) and that your port is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the trailing '/' in SolrUrl in your XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1. An additional '/' is the likely culprit.